# How to stop Tweenmax animation while animating

Tags: jquery, gsap

I have tried to stop animation before complete the animation in TweenMax. Initially div top is '0px'. I am animating it to top '90px' in 3 seconds. If I click on button I want stop it. How to get it?

```
    TweenMax.to("div", 3, {
        top: '90px',
    }); 
    <div id="stop">stop</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `kill()` to remove the tween.

JS: **To remove a tween.**

```
 var tween = TweenMax.to('div', 3, { top: '90px' }); 
 //then later...
 tween.kill();
```

[Source](http://greensock.com/forums/topic/2298-stop-a-tween-when-leaving-frame/?p=4803)

Answer (score 2):

You should use `killTweensOf`, such as:

```
$("#stop").click(function(){
    TweenMax.killTweensOf('div');
}
```

Source: https://greensock.com/docs/TweenMax/static.killTweensOf

Answer (score 0):

For that you will need to use the TimeLine from GSAP.

A simple example on how you can use that:

CDN for the TimeLine plugin:

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.5/TimelineLite.min.js
```

Small snippet to use it:

```
var toolTimeline = new TimelineMax();
toolTimeline.to("div",3, { top: '90px', });

$("#stop").click(function(){
    toolTimeline.stop();
})
```

Clicking on the button with id "stop" will stop/pause it.

Comment: It's not necessary to use TimelineMax to kill a tween